# How does text processing works?

Tags: string, text

Consider the whole novel (e.g. The Da Vinci Code).

How does e-book reader software process and output the whole book??

Does it put the WHOLE book in one very large string?? array of strings?? Or what??

Comment: As far as The Da Vinci Code is concerned, any sensible word processor simply moves it to `/dev/null` :-P

Answer (score 0):

One of the very first "real" programs I wrote (as part of a class excersise in high school) was a text editor. Part of the requirement for this excersise was for the program to be able to handle documents of arbitrary length (ie larger than the available system memory).

We achieved this by opening the file, but reading only the portion of it required to display the current page of data. When the user moves forward or backward in the file, we read that portion of the file and display it.

We can speed the program up by reading ahead to load pages which we anticipate that the user will want, and by retaining recently read pages in memory so that there is no obvious delay when the user moves forward or backward.

So basically, the answer to your question is: "No. with very large text files, it is unusual to load the whole thing into memory at once. A program that can handle files like that will load it in chunks as it needs to, and drop chunks it doesn't need any more."

Complex document formats (such as ebooks) may have lookup tables built into the file to allow the user to search or jump quickly to a given page or chapter. In this, they effectively work like a database.

I hope that helps.